# Enhancing a table

Tags: tables, syntax

I am writing to get your suggestion about how I could enhance a table. Please do not suggest changing color or fonts.

Code:

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Temporal Outliers that are detected with respect to the MetoSwiss Observations in $2007-09-30$}
\label{tod30f}
\centering
                \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Time - Node ID & 25 & 28 & 29 & 31 & 32 \\ \hline
0:00 & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal \\ \hline
1:00 & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal \\ \hline
2:00 & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal \\ \hline
3:00 & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal \\ \hline
4:00 & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal \\ \hline
5:00 & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal \\ \hline
6:00 & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal \\ \hline
7:00 & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal \\ \hline
8:00 & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal \\ \hline
9:00 & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal \\ \hline
10:00 & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal \\ \hline
11:00 & Outlier & Normal & Outlier & Normal & Normal \\ \hline
12:00 & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier \\ \hline
13:00 & Outlier & Normal & Normal & Normal & Outlier \\ \hline
14:00 & Outlier & Normal & Normal & Outlier & Outlier \\ \hline
15:00 & Outlier & Outlier & Normal & Outlier & Normal \\ \hline
16:00 & Normal & Outlier & Normal & Normal & Normal \\ \hline
17:00 & Normal & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Normal \\ \hline
18:00 & Outlier & Normal & Outlier & Outlier & Normal \\ \hline
19:00 & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier \\ \hline
20:00 & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier \\ \hline
21:00 & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal & Normal \\ \hline
22:00 & Normal & Normal & Normal & Outlier & Normal \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Result of the code:

[image]

Comment: texdoc booktabs

Comment: I would just remove the *Normal* text and leave only the outliers then change the *outlier* text to something like a `$\circ$` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`booktabs`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/booktabs) is a great resource for `tables`.

In particular, it provides the commands `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`. It also recommends *not* to use vertical lines in `tabulars`.

Here's a version of your table

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Temporal Outliers that are detected with respect to the MetoSwiss Observations in $2007-09-30$}
    \label{tod30f}
    \centering
    \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \hline
        Time - Node ID & 25      & 28      & 29      & 31      & 32      \\ \toprule
        0:00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ \midrule
        1:00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        2:00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        3:00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        4:00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        5:00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        6:00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        7:00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        8:00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        9:00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        10:00          & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        11:00          & Outlier & Normal  & Outlier & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        12:00          & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier \\ 
        13:00          & Outlier & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Outlier \\ 
        14:00          & Outlier & Normal  & Normal  & Outlier & Outlier \\ 
        15:00          & Outlier & Outlier & Normal  & Outlier & Normal  \\ 
        16:00          & Normal  & Outlier & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        17:00          & Normal  & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Normal  \\ 
        18:00          & Outlier & Normal  & Outlier & Outlier & Normal  \\ 
        19:00          & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier \\ 
        20:00          & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier \\ 
        21:00          & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        22:00          & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Outlier & Normal  \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You can further improve it by loading the [`caption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption) package with `format=hang`, and using

```
    \begin{tabular}{r@{:}l*{5}c}
```

to help with the alignment of the 'time' column. I have also put the 'Node ID' over the numbers using `\multicolumn` and `\cmidrule`.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Temporal Outliers that are detected with respect to the MetoSwiss Observations in $2007-09-30$}
    \label{tod30f}
    \centering
    \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{r@{:}l*{5}c}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{}&              & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Node ID}\\ \cmidrule{3-7}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Time} & 25      & 28      & 29      & 31      & 32      \\ \toprule
        0&00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ \midrule
        1&00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        2&00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        3&00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        4&00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        5&00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        6&00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        7&00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        8&00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        9&00           & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        10&00          & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        11&00          & Outlier & Normal  & Outlier & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        12&00          & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier \\ 
        13&00          & Outlier & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Outlier \\ 
        14&00          & Outlier & Normal  & Normal  & Outlier & Outlier \\ 
        15&00          & Outlier & Outlier & Normal  & Outlier & Normal  \\ 
        16&00          & Normal  & Outlier & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        17&00          & Normal  & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Normal  \\ 
        18&00          & Outlier & Normal  & Outlier & Outlier & Normal  \\ 
        19&00          & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier \\ 
        20&00          & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier & Outlier \\ 
        21&00          & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  \\ 
        22&00          & Normal  & Normal  & Normal  & Outlier & Normal  \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah look at the indentation... ;)

Comment: @percusse yep, `indent.plx` worked well on this one :)

Comment: Is there anyway to simple convert of my other tables to booklet format?

Comment: @cmhughes, How can I move the "Node Id " to the top of 25,28,29,31 and 32 as header. Subsequently put the time on first column header.

Comment: @Topdombili see the update :) converting your other tables will be either have to be done tediously by hand, or else using a text processing script, such as `perl`; it shouldn't be too much work to search and replace for `\hline`

Answer (score 9):

[image]

`Booktabs`, can help with the typesetting. Rethinking the way you present the data is also important. First thing I did when I looked at the data was to see where was the data; it was lost in a sea of "Normal"; I am not sure what your "normal" is, or what an "outlier" is, but here is an alternative presentation.

Comment: very nice. Removing the clutter of date can improve presentation more than any amount of formatting.

Comment: @devendra so true...